# What is the best/most standard way to measure server load?

Tags: web-applications, server, amazon-ec2

I'm a bit green to web applications although I am in the final phases of developing one for a client. I'm using Django with Gunicorn/Nginx on an AWS m1.medium. The database (MongoDB) is on a separate instance. The client is paranoid about scaling and so I threw together a crude monitoring server which has the ability to spin up new AWS instances, install the app code and load balance (I know, I know, I could have used ELB. I said I was green, and it was fun writing it anyway).

The question is, I don't really know what metrics I should be aware of. How will I know when my app server is under 'high load'? CPU? RAM? Request latency? All of the above?

Any guidance in this area would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High load is too high when either *software is unstable*, or *users start to notice latencies*, whichever comes first. You should know your usage pattern, and build load tests based on it.
Pick the bottleneck factor (cpu, ram, io) and fire up instances at 80% of the peak value, to handle spikes. Also you start/shutdown them before busiest/most idle times of the day.

Comment: Thanks. Based on my stack, what would you guess my metrics should tell? How would I load test this?

Comment: It depends heavily on what your system do. Can't guess. Do you compress video? Or increase a lone counter? (just kidding) If you don't know your load you wasting time in premature optimisation. You can't place a metric on an idle system.

Comment: (can't edit previous one) Use top for cpu, iotop for io monitoring. You will know overload and how the system handels it when you rack load test enough up.